# Error when trying to insert a record to a table which has an association to two other tables

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

I'm new in designing relational Databases. I need to design a Relational Database for a pharmacy. It needs to keep up with the orders and sales. I created the following relational database using entity data model. When I try to add a new entry for an order it tells me that I need to add a Distributor. But when I try to do that in Linq to Entity (order1.Distributor.Add(distributor1) it wont show me the Add method. Whats wrong with my design or code. Both are shown below. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

[image: EDM]

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new EDM1Container())
        {
            PProducts product1 = new PProducts
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "aspirin",
                Price = "12"
            };

            PProducts product2 = new PProducts
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Alkaseltzer",
                Price = "1"
            };

             Distributor distributor1 = new Distributor
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "USMedicineSupply",
            Telephone = "985-001-8745"
        };

        POrders order1 = new POrders
        {
            Id = 1,
            Date = "3/7/2015"
        };

        order1.PProducts.Add(product1);
        order1.PProducts.Add(product2);            
        context.POrders.AddObject(order1);
        context.SaveChanges();
        //order1.Distributor.Add(distributor1); -> it wont show me the Add method

        }


    }
```

Comment: Assuming that your `Id` fields are `auto-incrementing` you don't need to set them on your `button1_Click` function

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge of linq but I think you're up against the classic order tracking problem.

When tracking orders you might expect orders and products to be related as your diagram showed - one order, many products, but each product, single order.

It isn't - if the products are standard, stock ones, then the same product could be sold through many orders, giving you a table in between:

```
Order(id,date) 
orderLINE(POrderID, lineNum, PProductID, Quantity_ordered)
product(id,desc, price, ... )
```

An order has many LINES, a product also features in many lines (of different orders).

I hope this helps you despite my inexperience of linq. If not, I can live with downvotes, or comment below.

Comment: So you are saying that it should be a many to many relationship between POrders and PProducts ? Also where can I see some Examples of Order Tracking Products

Comment: many-to-many: absolutely. Examples of off-the-shelf order tracking systems: there are many, though they will tend to do more than the system you are showing here, which is on a smaller scale. But you could look at the OpenCart database if you want an example.